# Typo3 tx_news filter multiple categories. AND instead of OR?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I implemented a tx_news filter to filter multiple categories with this code:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/MultiCategorySelection/Index.html

This is working fine with some little customization here: https://2022.asienhaus.de/themen/

The filter is using OR to filter categories: Filter news with CategoryA OR CategoryB
Is it possible to filter with AND: Filter news with CategoryA AND CategoryB?

Thank you for your help.
Jürgen

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this was too easy...I found the solution: in the corresponding list element, I can choose the category mode AND, OR and more